# Update a whole column instead of a row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ok is there a possibility to update a column instead of a row?

f.e something like that:

```
$laninpstmt = $db->prepare ("UPDATE table SET column_name WHERE id = :allids");

$laninpstmt->bindParam(':allids', $_POST['input0']);

$laninpstmt->bindParam(':allids', $_POST['input1']);

$laninpstmt->bindParam(':allids', $_POST['input2']);

$laninpstmt->bindParam(':allids', $_POST['input3']);

$laninpstmt->bindParam(':allids', $_POST['input3']);
```

If i explain the code it's like: 
Update all the rows(allids) from one column in a table

Answer (score 2):

Running your query without a where clause will update all rows, and if you update a single field it will be the same as updating a column

```
UPDATE `test` SET `field_5` = 7
```

Will update table `test` and set all values in the column `field_5` to 7

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify the value for you column_name like that

```
   UPDATE table SET column_name = 'Some_value here' WHERE id = :allids
```

i guess you want do this

```
$laninpstmt = $db->prepare ("UPDATE table SET column_name = Concat(:allids1 , :allids2, :allids3, :allids4) WHERE id = :allids");
$laninpstmt->bindParam(':allids', $_POST['input0']);

$laninpstmt->bindParam(':allids1', $_POST['input1']);

$laninpstmt->bindParam(':allids2', $_POST['input2']);

$laninpstmt->bindParam(':allids3', $_POST['input3']);

$laninpstmt->bindParam(':allids4', $_POST['input4']);
```

Comment: Well i know, but if my column has to stay like it was i do not need to add a value i suppose?

Comment: didnt got what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [IN](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm):

Apparently, you need to do your own query, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/920523/2575355.

```
$inputs = array($_POST['input0'], $_POST['input1'], $_POST['input2']);
$allids = implode(', ', $inputs)

$laninpstmt = $db->prepare ("UPDATE table SET column_name WHERE id IN ($allids)");
```